# How to find the count of a particular number that can exist in 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-quicksight

[image: eg. of current table]

I have a table that consist of a table that describes calls. Hence there is a `to` column and a `from` column. The problem is that I want the total messages sent by each number, which can be `from` or `to`. Refer to the table above for visuals.

I want the final table to be somethng that shows A : 3 , B: 2 , C:1 and D:1.

How do u count the numbers in 2 columns and sum them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to first `UNION ALL` two aggregate queries to gather the count of occurences of each value in the two different columns, and them sum the results in an outer query, like:

```
SELECT val, SUM(cnt) cnt
FROM (
    SELECT `from` val, COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY `from`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `to`, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY `to`
) x
GROUP BY val
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6v5MFtzqwBZErFN7FWSz5a/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| val | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| A   | 3   |
| B   | 2   |
| C   | 1   |
| D   | 1   |
| E   | 1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select person, count(*) as num_calls
from ((select from as person from t) union all
      (select to as person from t
     ) c
group by person;
```

Note that `from` and `to` are really, really bad names for columns because they are SQL keywords.  I haven't escaped them in the query, because that just clutters the query and I assume the real columns have better names.